# Input function interpreted as variable for some reason

Tags: python

Been looking around and can't find an answer.

So I call either raw_input() or input() to fill out a simple variable. But instead of running the function, I get

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment
```

My code doesn't have 'input()' anywhere before that first call, and never makes a variable sharing the name. Same happens for 'raw_input()'. I'm confused here, as calls to the functions work fine in other code, and also on the console, but for some reason throw errors on this. No previous calls. Funny enough, it worked on my first run of the code, but now doesn't. What am I looking for?

Edit: Someone asked for the code. Not much to show.

```
end = False
lightsoff = []
lightson = []
bias = []
i = 0
while not end:
    print "Set #" + str(i + 1) +", LED off: ",
    offFile = input()
```

EDIT: To correct here, a variable named 'input' is referred to much later in the code (it's long). I wrote a couple of references backwards. I didn't know Python made a list (or something) of what's going to be a local variable before running, thus throwing up problems like this.

Comment: Can you show us your code that acutally produces that error?

Comment: `input` *is* a variable; it's a reference to a built-in function. Somewhere later in your code, though, you are assigning a non-callable object to the same name, making it a local unassigned variable that shadows the built-in name.

Comment: It's working for me!

Comment: Is this really th whole source code?

Comment: This is obviously not the relevant part of the code here since there's no 'input' variable in this snippet but the error message explicitly mentions it ...

Comment: Nah, that wasn't the whole source code. It's much longer and I didn't want to bring over all of it.

Comment: To ensure that we can actually do something besides guessing please make sure that you include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your questions ;>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your code looks a bit like:

```
>>> def x():
...     input = input()
...     print(input)
... 
>>> x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in x
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

The problem is that you've created a variable called 'input', and then trying to get something from it before it exists.

```
>>> def y():
...     val = input()
...     print(val)
... 
>>> y()
```

Would work a bit better.  In python (and most dynamic languages) functions are kind of values too - so you can use the name of a function just like you would any other variable.

So a good idea is to not name a variable the same as a function.

Does that help?

Comment: No, I don't have a variable named after the function. That would be a pretty bad thing to do. EDIT: Hmmm, wait, I found it later in the code? Weird that the code would know it's coming. I was only looking for problems in the code in advance. I didn't know Python did this.

Comment: @Dani at compile time, Python detects which names are assigned to within a function's body and - unless those names are explicitely declared as global or nonlocal - marks those names as local variables. This is required since Python has no explicit variable declaration.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense as a solution for no declarations. Thanks guys!